# Use $lookup with a Conditional Join

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

provided I have following documents

**User**

```
{
    uuid: string,
    isActive: boolean,
    lastLogin: datetime,
    createdOn: datetime
}
```

**Projects**

```
{
    id: string,
    users: [
        {
            uuid: string,
            otherInfo: ...
        },
        {... more users}
    ]
}
```

And I want to select all users that didn't login since 2 weeks and are inactive or since 5 weeks  that don't have projects.

Now, the 2 weeks is working fine but I cannot seem to figure out how to do the "5 weeks and don't have projects" part

I came up with something like below but the last part does not work because `$exists` obviously is not a top level operator.

Anyone ever did anything like this?
Thanks!

```
return await this.collection
    .aggregate([
        {
            $match: {
                $and: [
                    {
                        $expr: {
                            $allElementsTrue: {
                                $map: {
                                    input: [`$lastLogin`, `$createdOn`],
                                    in: { $lt: [`$$this`, twoWeeksAgo] }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $or: [
                            {
                                isActive: false
                            },
                            {
                                $and: [
                                    {
                                        $expr: {
                                            $allElementsTrue: {
                                                $map: {
                                                    input: [`$lastLogin`, `$createdOn`],
                                                    in: { $lt: [`$$this`, fiveWeeksAgo] }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        //No projects exists on this user
                                        $exists: {
                                            $lookup: {
                                                from: _.get(Config, `env.collection.projects`),
                                                let: {
                                                    currentUser: `$$ROOT`
                                                },
                                                pipeline: [
                                                    {
                                                        $project: {
                                                            _id: 0,
                                                            users: {
                                                                $filter: {
                                                                    input: `$users`,
                                                                    as: `user`,
                                                                    cond: {
                                                                        $eq: [`$$user.uuid`, `$currentUser.uuid`]
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ])
    .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain why you thought [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) was needed in the initial [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), but really:

```
const getResults = () => {

  const now = Date.now();
  const twoWeeksAgo = new Date(now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 2 ));
  const fiveWeeksAgo = new Date(now - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 5 ));

  // as long a mongoDriverCollectionReference points to a "Collection" object
  // for the "users" collection

  return mongoDriverCollectionReference.aggregate([   
    // No $expr, since you can actually use an index. $expr cannot do that
    { "$match": {
      "$or": [
        // Active and "logged in"/created in the last 2 weeks
        { 
          "isActive": true,
          "$or": [
            { "lastLogin": { "$gte": twoWeeksAgo } },
            { "createdOn": { "$gte": twoWeeksAgo } }
          ]
        },
        // Also want those who...
        // Not Active and "logged in"/created in the last 5 weeks
        // we'll "tag" them later
        { 
          "isActive": false,
          "$or": [
            { "lastLogin": { "$gte": fiveWeeksAgo } },
            { "createdOn": { "$gte": fiveWeeksAgo } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }},

    // Now we do the "conditional" stuff, just to return a matching result or not

    { "$lookup": {
      "from":  _.get(Config, `env.collection.projects`), // there are a lot cleaner ways to register models than this
      "let": {
        "uuid": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": "$isActive",   // this is boolean afterall
            "then": null,       // don't really want to match
            "else": "$uuid"     // Okay to match the 5 week results
          }
        }
      },
      "pipeline": [
        // Nothing complex here as null will return nothing. Just do $in for the array
        { "$match": {  "$in": [ "$$uuid", "$users.uuid" ] } },

        // Don't really need the detail, so just reduce any matches to one result of [null]
        { "$group": { "_id": null } }
      ],
      "as": "projects"
    }},

    // Now test if the $lookup returned something where it mattered
    { "$match": {
      "$or": [
        { "active": true },                   // remember we selected the active ones already
        {
          "projects.0": { "$exists": false }  // So now we only need to know the "inactive" returned no array result.
        }
      ]
    }}
  ]).toArray();   // returns a Promise
};
```

It's pretty simple as calculated expressions via [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) are actually really bad and not what you want in a first pipeline stage. Also *"not what you need"* since `createdOn` and `lastLogin` really should not have been merged into an array for [`$allElementsTrue`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/allElementsTrue/) which would just be an **AND** condition, where you described logic would really mean **OR**. So the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) does just fine here.

So does the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) on the separation of conditions for the `isActive` of `true/false`. Again it's *either* "two weeks" **OR** "five weeks". And this certainly does not need [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) since standard inequality range matching works fine, and uses an "index".

Then you really just want to do the *"conditional"* things in the `let` for [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) instead of your *"does it exist"* thinking. All you really need to know ( since the range selection of dates is actually already done ) is whether `active` is now `true` or `false`. Where it's `active` ( meaning by your logic you don't care about projects ) simply make the `$$uuid` used within the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage a `null` value so it will not match and the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) returns an **empty array**. Where `false` ( also already matching the date conditions from earlier ) then you use the actual value and "join" ( where there are projects of course ).

Then it's just a simple matter of keeping the `active` users, and then only testing the remaining `false` values for `active` to see if the `"projects"` array from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) actually returned anything. If it did not, then they just don't have projects.

Probably should note here is since `users` is an "array" within the `projects` collection, you use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) for the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) condition against the single value to the array.

Note that for *brevity* we can use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) inside the inner pipeline to only return **one** result instead of possibly many matches to actual matched projects. You don't care about the content or the *"count"*, but simply if **one** was returned or **nothing**. Again following the presented logic.

This gets you your desired results, and it does so in a manner that is efficient and actually uses indexes where available.

Also `return await` certainly does not do what you think it does, and in fact it's an ESLint warning message ( I suggest you enable ESLint in your project ) since it's not a smart thing to do. It does nothing really, as you would need to `await getResults()` ( as per the example naming ) anyway, as the `await` keyword is not *"magic"* but just a *prettier* way of writing `then()`. As well as hopefully being easier to understand, once you understand what `async/await` is really for syntactically that is.

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver! Thank you so much, also for this extended information. I will start tweaking my query with you propositions for sure! Again, thank you!